# How do I authenticate/protect non api_views with DRF + JWT eg. rendering a private page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I understand how to protect this for example, get the token, store it as cookie, then get the access token via the cookie and send it via Ajax to /api/hello and I get my JSON

```
@api_view()
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def hello(request):
    return Response({'message': 'hello this is protected'})
```

But how would I protect this page where I want only people who are authenticated to see the page, eg. if they click this URL /secretmessage

```
def secret_message(request):
return render(request, 'secret_message.html')
```

Am I supposed to use a combination of JWT auth for the API stuff and Session Based auth and not just rely on JWT for all auth?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def secret_message(request):
return render(request, 'secret_message.html')
```

Use `@login_required` decorator, to allows only users who are logged in to access the view.

Comment: Isn't this only for Session based auth? I am using JWT

Comment: Can you elaborate your use case, And are you using a coupled application where the frontend and backend are in oner application.  or a decoupled one like a React Frontend and Django Backend.  When does the user transition to the `secret_message.html` page in the use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want in this case you could create your own decorator which could answer if the user logged in with jwt or not.
This could be an example:

```
decorators.py

from functools import wraps
from django.http import JsonResponse
import jwt

def api_login_required(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        token = request.request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
        if token == None:
            return JsonResponse({'message':"Error: Unauthenticated..."})
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
        except Exception: #jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            return JsonResponse({'message':"Error: Unauthenticated..."})
        if payload:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'message':"Error: Unauthenticated..."})
    return wrap
```

Then you would only have to make the call with @api_login_required

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@api_login_required
def secret_message(request):
return render(request, 'secret_message.html')
```